# image looks different after using cv::resize

Tags: qt, opencv

The program is a video player which allows user to zoom in and reset specific frames.I use QLabel to display frames from the video capture.The zoom in function works perfectly, but when it comes to reset, the result image becomes black and white and with a strange angle.（looks like some pats of the image moved to the right side,which are supposed to be at the left side）.it looks like this picture below.

My reputation is too low to post an image.So please visit https://i.stack.imgur.com/WddWU.png
(I don't know whether the link will works or not).

I want the right one, but the program shows the left one

I used Qt 5.12 and opencv 3 at Windows10 platform.

```
//this one works well
    void playVideo::on_zoomInBtn_clicked()
    {
       ui->zoomOutBtn->setEnabled(true);
       statusBar()->showMessage("zoomin*2",1000);
       Mat scaleFrame;
       cv::resize(this->frame,scaleFrame,Size(0,0),2, 2,CV_INTER_LINEAR);
       QImage img=QImage(scaleFrame.data,scaleFrame.cols,scaleFrame.rows,QImage::Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped();
       ui->videoPlayArea->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));
    }


//this one works bad
    void playVideo::on_zoomOutBtn_clicked()
    {
        statusBar()->showMessage("zoomout",1000);
        Mat scaleFrame;
        ui->videoPlayArea->setFixedSize(QSize(701,371));
        cv::resize(this->frame,scaleFrame,Size(701,371),CV_INTER_AREA);
        imshow("name",scaleFrame);
        QImage img=QImage(scaleFrame.data,scaleFrame.cols,scaleFrame.rows,QImage::Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped();
        img.scaled(ui->videoPlayArea->width(),ui->videoPlayArea->height(),Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio,Qt::SmoothTransformation);
           ui->videoPlayArea->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));
    }
```

I want a colorful image not a black and white one.
Can somebody help me?I am new to both Qt and opencv.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I guess unaligned scanlines. See the [docs of `QImage`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#QImage-3)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I fond my problem.It turned out that I misused a parameter when I try to convert Mat to QImage.The correct code should be like this:QImage img=QImage(scaleFrame.data, scaleFrame.cols, scaleFrame.rows, scaleFrame.step, QImage::Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped();